# Narrowing the range to add Hyperlinks

Tags: vba, ms-word

I extract sentences of a document containing a pattern resembling to 23/25.
Done with reg. expressions.
The issue : having the content of the hyperlink I want to add to this 23/25 change when a specific word is found in the sentence extracted with the regexes.

The code I found to add a hyperlink doesn't let me narrow the range to the very sentence found and has me use the Activedocument.range, so the entire doc content.
With the code hereunder, all occurrences of say 23/25 will end up with the same hyperlink.

Is there a way to set/narrow the range specifically to the sentence found with the regexes?

I know the code hereunder is definitely not properly written, I'm struggling here. Thanks for your kind help in advance.

```
Set objRegex = New RegExp
With objRegex
   .Pattern = "(\d{2}/\d{2})([a-zA-Zé /'/., ]{2,250})"
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = True
Set matches = .Execute(Txte)
For Each fnd In matches
a = fnd.SubMatches.Count
For i = 0 To a - 1
    If InStr(fnd, "cdtional word") Then
        resul = fnd.SubMatches.Item(1)
Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range{resul}
With Rng.Find
   Do While .Execute(findText:=resul, Forward:=False) = True
       Rng.MoveEndUntil (" ")
       ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _
       Anchor:=Rng, _
       Address:="https://bla.org/" & resul
       Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
   Loop`
```

(closing tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, please fix it. Thanks. I can only use what you have given and deal with it temporarily as an answer. If it does not meet your needs, please forgive me.

And I don't have a text for testing, so I can't do the actual testing. As in these lines, I don't know what you are doing：

```vb
            If InStr(fnd, "cdtional word") Then
                resul = fnd.SubMatches.Item(1)
```

So the code I suppose should be:

```vb
Sub VBA__MSWORD__Narrowing_the_range_to_add_Hyperlinks()
    Dim objRegex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection, fnd As VBScript_RegExp_55.match
    Dim Txte As String, d As Document, resul As String, a As Long, i As Long, rng As Range
    
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Txte = d.Content.Text
    
    Set objRegex = New RegExp
    With objRegex
       .Pattern = "(\d{2}/\d{2})([a-zA-Zé /'/., ]{2,250})"
       .Global = True
       .IgnoreCase = True
        Set matches = .Execute(Txte)
    End With
    For Each fnd In matches
        a = fnd.SubMatches.Count
        For i = 0 To a - 1
            If InStr(fnd, "cdtional word") Then
                resul = fnd.SubMatches.Item(1)
            '    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range{resul}
                Set rng = d.Range
                With rng.Find
                   'Do While .Execute(findText:=resul, Forward:=False) = True
                   Do While .Execute(findText:=resul, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
                       rng.MoveEndUntil (" ")
'                       ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _
'                       Anchor:=rng, _
'                       Address:="https://bla.org/" & resul
'                       rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart

                       Rem Try to use rng instead of ActiveDocument
                       rng.Hyperlinks.Add _
                       Anchor:=rng, _
                       Address:="https://bla.org/" & resul
                       rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                       
                       If rng.Next Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                       Rem Reset the range to be searched:
                       rng.SetRange rng.Next.Start, d.Content.End
                       
                   Loop
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    Next fnd
End Sub
```

You should modify my code to apply according to your actual needs.

## 20230603 Without [Find object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find)

No need to use the Find object

- [the Test File](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13po-VCn4y7Dwz9FNTjn6fosR7k9G2GDv/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106108182093734588005&rtpof=true&sd=true)
- [How to download the .docm *(the MS Word document file with VBA code)* file from Google Drive.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yVlDI8JN8U&t=53s)

```vb
Option Explicit
'Private linkDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Private linkDict As Object
Rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76386857/vba-msword-narrowing-the-range-to-add-hyperlinks
Rem Dear Omar: the sample text and result is this : Document 25/23 from company X is to be reviewed. Document 25/23 from Company Z as well. – 
Rem I just need the VBA to 1) look for all sentences containing 25/23 , 2) add 1 hyperlink to 25/23 : if the word "Company X" is in that sentence, the hyperlink has to be Http://docs.org/Startups/25/23. But if the word "Company Z" is in that sentence, then the hyperlink has to be Https://docs.org/ngos/25/23 instead. That is all I need really – 

Rem All string comparisons are case-sensitive
Sub VBA_MSWORD_Narrowing_the_range_to_add_Hyperlinks()
    Dim objRegex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection, fnd As VBScript_RegExp_55.match
    Dim Txte As String, d As Document, resul As String, a As Long, i As Long, rng As Range, ur As UndoRecord, s As Long
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "VBA_MSWORD_Narrowing_the_range_to_add_Hyperlinks"
    
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Txte = d.Content.Text
    Set rng = d.Range
    
    Set objRegex = New RegExp 'Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Research:
    With objRegex
'       .Pattern = "(\d{2}/\d{2})([a-zA-Zé /'/., ]{2,250})"
       .Pattern = "(\d{2}/\d{2})([a-zA-Zé /'/., ]{2,250})(Company [A-Z])"
       .Global = True
       .IgnoreCase = True
       '.MultiLine=False 'default
       Set matches = .Execute(Txte)
    End With
    For Each fnd In matches
        a = fnd.SubMatches.Count
        For i = 0 To a - 1
'            If InStr(fnd, "Company ") Then ' this can be omitted because regex is already applying to
                resul = fnd.SubMatches.Item(2)
                With rng
                    .SetRange fnd.FirstIndex + s, fnd.FirstIndex + s + VBA.Len(fnd.SubMatches.Item(0))
                    '.Select 'just for test watching only
                       .Hyperlinks.Add _
                       Anchor:=rng, _
                       Address:=GetLink(resul)
                       'rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

                       'If rng.Next Is Nothing Then Exit Sub to end this procedure
                       If rng.Next Is Nothing Then
                            ur.EndCustomRecord
                            Exit Sub
                       End If
                       Rem Reset the range to be searched:
                       s = rng.Next.Start
                       rng.SetRange s, d.Content.End
                       
                       Txte = rng.Text
                       GoTo Research
                End With
'            End If
        Next i
    Next fnd
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub

Property Get GetLink(company As String) As String
    'If linkDict.Count = 0 Then
    If linkDict Is Nothing Then
        Set linkDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With linkDict
            .Add "Company X", "http://docs.org/Startups/25/23" ' "http"? did you lost the "s" ?
            .Add "Company Z", "https://docs.org/ngos/25/23"
        End With
    End If
    GetLink = linkDict(company)
End Property
```

[image: Is this what you really want?]

Is this what you really want? If there are other relevant details you did not or forgot to mention, you should try to make adjustments yourself. I should have done already my best to fulfill what you said to me.

Comment: Zillion thanks for your detailed answer Oscar. Eye-opening. The text goes like "Document 23/25 from company X has to be reviewed; document 23/25 from company Y as well". The hyperlinks added to 23/25 needing to be different as explained. You commented the Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range{resul}. While that line is not properly formated, don't I still need to add Set rng = smthg ? and = what?  As such the code you modified throws me the "Object variable or With block variable not set " error.  Just not sure what to set the rng to.... Any clue perhaps ? Tx again, really.

Comment: and for the sake of being thorough in my answer since you ask : with  If InStr(fnd, "cdtional word") Then   resul = fnd.SubMatches.Item(1)     I was trying to use groups to extract the 23/25 from the sentence found with the regexpattern in the hope obviously to add a specific hyperlink link on it afterwards in the code.

Comment: @OmarKend Sorry, I left out this line because I couldn't test it: `Set rng = d.Range` and already updated my code. As well, I still can't actually test it because I don't have the data available for testing, so I'll have to ask you to let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you again Oscar. I'm sure I'm pretty much there thanks to your invaluable input. But now Word keeps looping and I get a "Word 9not Responding). Don't see why since your code seems straightforward.  Any clue perhaps ?

Comment: @OmarKend It may be the displacement of the Range position after inserting the hyperlink, please try this instead `rng.SetRange rng.Next.Start, d.Content.End`.Plz, see my updated code.

Comment: One more thing : I really need to work on the sentence level here and not the paragraph level as far as the range is concerned. The logic being if 25/23 is found in a sentence and if the word X is also in this very sentence, then add this specific hyperlink to 25/23 (the word X defines the actual hyperlink content). Dwelving in the code, I don't feel I operate on the sentence found (through the regex) level. Am I wrong and if not how to manage that?

Comment: @OmarKend You'd better make a break point here in the *Loop* to monitor whether the hyperlink insertion facility is correct, so that it doesn't become an endless loop

Comment: @OmarKend Sorry. I can't know exactly what the problem is without knowing your situation. If the text you are looking for appears multiple times in the same paragraph or document, and you want to locate the exact position, then the current code should not be able to handle it precisely. (Because it has to be adjusted according to your actual needs. (You also have to make sure that your regular expressions are getting the right results.)

Comment: @OmarKend But the principles shouldn't be outside the scope of the code I gave you. You shouldn't just ask me, because, after all, I don't have your information and background to grasp everything exactly, not to mention that I can't even test the program now.

Comment: The code you gave me works now, but all 25/23 found in the text are given the same hyperlink, not a different one (a specific word (different each time) being present in the sentence found through the regexes). Can't tell you how thankful I am for your input and time Oscar. You are a gem. Maybe someone else has a clue to help me achieve that?? Document 25/23 from company X is to be reviewed. Document 25/23 from Company Z as well.  First hyperlink to be added (Http://docs.org/Startups/25/23, second hyperlink to be added Https://docs.org/ngos/25/23

Comment: @OmarKend You must give me a minimum sample of what you want the results to look like. I can't help you if I don't follow it. Also, your English is very difficult for me to read.It is better to have a shared file that can be edited collaboratively.And don't forget what string the user inputs to the regular expression judgment I think you understand the reason why the clever woman can not cook without rice

Comment: Dear Omar: the sample text and result is this  : Document 25/23 from company X is to be reviewed. Document 25/23 from Company Z as well.

Comment: I just need the VBA to 1) look for all sentences containing 25/23 , 2) add 1 hyperlink to 25/23 : if the word "Company X" is in that sentence, the hyperlink has to be Http://docs.org/Startups/25/23. But if the word "Company Z" is in that sentence, then the hyperlink has to be  Https://docs.org/ngos/25/23 instead. That is all I need really

Comment: @OmarKend All right, try the new one at the end of my answer. Thank you. If that's what you want to do, please accept the answer to end this question. And *Your code is incomplete, please fix it.* I told you before, you have not done it yet.

Comment: This is beyond my wildest expectations Oscar. Thank you for taking the time to show me how to structure this properly. Going to learn a lot from this. I'm sure it could help others since coding is a matter of finding the right approach. Thank you again for your time and understanding.